# Redirect Page Login google

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, oauth

I see this tutorial about Google Authenticantion: [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZtDJ3S0MT0)

But my button of google:

[image]

Redirect to a page that needs to click continue to redirect to the login page, but what I would like is that as soon as I click on the google login button, I will be redirected to the login page, without this intermediate page

[image]

Below my settings

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only necessary to make a `form.submit()` with javascript to redirect directly to the page